# Prevent value binding from updating object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js to initialize edit form values like this:

```
<input id="editapp-name" name="name" placeholder="Enter app name"
    type="text" data-bind="value: editapp().name" />
```

However, I don't want the model to be updated unless the user clicks on the Update button and I get a successful response from the server.

Can I do something like

```
data-bind="value: editapp().name, valueUpdate: 'no'"
```

Comment: Why don't you use a temp property like: `tempName` use that in your binding `data-bind="value: editapp().tempName"` and copy `tempName` to `name` when your server reports success? Maybe this article also give you some ideas: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using something like viewModel.editapp(new ObservableApplication(self.toPOJO()). Thanks anyway